# Client-side validation of Elasticsearch query string

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an application that uses NEST (Elasticsearch .NET client) to communicate with an Elasticsearch cluster. The integration allows the user to specify input for the "query_string" portion of a query.

The user may input an invalid query. Say "AND", which is invalid because the predicate is incomplete. But the error message that comes back from Elasticsearch is exceedingly verbose, and contains terminology that isn't very user-friendly, like "all shards failed".

Is there a way I can offer the user a more meaningful error message (say - "bad predicate"). Ideally, the users search string would be validated without an Elasticsearch round-trip, but I'll settle for a simpler error message however I can get it.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but as an FYI, it's generally a bad idea to expose the query string syntax directly to users.

Comment: @GregMarzouka I'm very interested in learning more about that. Any resources you can suggest?

Answer (score 2):

The error message returned by Elasticsearch is verbose but for parsing errors like these, Elasticsearch throws a `QueryParsingException`. If you examine the error message closely, you'll find the string `QueryParsingException` towards the end of the entire error message. This is the exception (and its message) you are interested in. For example, when I spelt `must` as `mus2t` in a search request, I get a huge error message by Elasticsearch and below is the last part of the error message.

```
QueryParsingException[[<index name>] bool query does not support [mus2t]]; }]
```

I got this when I spelt `must` as `mus2t`. You can parse and extract out this error message.

Comment: That works for me, I get `QueryParsingException[[<index name>] Failed to parse query [AND]]`. The next issue though is how to best parse that from the larger text. I could code a parser myself easily enough, but without any specification on the error text structure I won't know whether I'm missing any subtle details. Maybe other error scenarios have a rather different text format?

Comment: At first I marked this response as an answer, but in retrospect, though its a helpful insight it still falls well short of what I'm really looking for. If it's not a `QueryParsingException` for example, how do I get to a "user-friendly" error? How do I determine, based on error response, the difference between a critical server error like "disk is corrupt" and something far more mediocre like "badly formatted query"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [validation api](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_validating_queries.html).

For following query

```
var validateResponse = client.Validate<Document>(descriptor => descriptor
    .Explain()
    .Query(query => query
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .OnFields(f => f.Name)
            .Query("AND"))));
```

you will get

```
org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [indexname]
Failed to parse query [AND];
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse
'AND': Encountered " <AND> "AND "" at line 1, column 0. Was expecting
one of:
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...
    <TERM> ...
    "*" ...
```

Still not so perfect for end user and it requires round-trip to ES, but maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: Helpful, yes. I did already encounter the validation API and explored it as an option. I *could* pre-validate all queries, and that would at least make it clear whether an error was a query syntax error or something else. But it's a bit clumsy. As I said, ideally I can get validation without an extra round-trip, but more critically, this still doesn't give me a "simple error message".